# Equivalent method to `get_counts()` for `Aer_simulator`?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-quantum-devices, qiskit-runtime

I was working on a quantum circuit and recently switched from using a local `AerSimulator` to some of the quantum backends provided by IBM.

When I used `AerSimulator`:

Input:

```python
# QBPolynomial.M[0] contains the number of classical bits
qc.measure(self.bit_indices, range(QBPolynomial.M[0]))

job = sim.run(qc)
print(job.result().get_counts())
return list(job.result().get_counts().keys())[0][::-1]
```

Output:

```
{'0001': 1024}
```

Currently, I am using `ibm_osaka` quantum computer from IBM, and I have modified my code as follows:

Input:

```python
 qc.measure(self.bit_indices, range(QBPolynomial.M[0]))

 job = Sampler(backend).run(qc)
 print(job.result())
 return list(job.result().get_counts().keys())[0][::-1]
```

Output:

```
SamplerResult(quasi_dists=[{0: 0.06243554115541435, 1: 0.05970302455950597, 2: 0.06598716636786178, 3: 0.06819568716628542, 4: 0.061762903512773464, 5: 0.05666321180729433, 6: 0.053504833664354295, 7: 0.05565037752211716, 8: 0.0645535762394776, 9: 0.07333057480411498, 10: 0.06230084764424416, 11: 0.060209492533812546, 12: 0.06482058959267466, 13: 0.0607230201183338, 14: 0.06698430268824439, 15: 0.06317485062349108}], metadata=[{'shots': 4000, 'circuit_metadata': {}, 'readout_mitigation_overhead': 1.3097064541899894, 'readout_mitigation_time': 0.03967492887750268, 'warning': 'Optimization level clipped from 3 to 1'}])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adarsh/NITK/MP/Project/qbpolynomial.py", line 339, in <module>
    print(qpoly3)
  File "/home/adarsh/NITK/MP/Project/qbpolynomial.py", line 306, in __str__
    coeffs = self.measure()
  File "/home/adarsh/NITK/MP/Project/qbpolynomial.py", line 227, in measure
    return list(job.result().get_counts().keys())[0][::-1]
AttributeError: 'SamplerResult' object has no attribute 'get_counts'
```

How can I get an output equivalent to `AerSimulator`'s `get_counts` method? The `quasi_dicts` is not exactly a one-to-one mapping to `get_counts()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making use of `Sampler` and want the same result as the `get_counts` one, the `samplerResult` is still a dictionary, you can extract results out of it.

Taking from your code, instead of

```python
 job = Sampler(backend).run(qc)
 print(job.result())
 return list(job.result().get_counts().keys())[0][::-1]
```

Do this

```python
sampler = Sampler(backend=backend)
samp_dist = sampler.run(qc).result().quasi_dists[0]
```

and then if you want to order them from highest to lowest (probability wise)

```python
my_dict = dict(sorted(samp_dist.binary_probabilities().items(),key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
print(my_dict)
```

This will print a result like this:

`{'0101': 0.1435546875, '1010': 0.134765625, '0011': 0.1123046875}`